# I cannot install flash player, I am getting 1603 exit code

Tags: installation, flash-player

I am trying to install flash player silently, using a powershell script. I do not think it is being installed.  I looked under "control panel->uninstall programs"  I don't see flash player listed there.
Also, I am printing the exit code for the process and it prints 1603 exit code, which is "fatal error during installation"

As an experiment, I double click on the flash player .msi file, and it gave me 1722 error " Error 1722.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. "

Comment: It would help if you posted the script that you're using to install. Also, have you tried downloading another copy of the MSI? Perhaps there is a problem with the download.

Comment: stop-process -ProcessName 'ieexplore'                                   msiexec /i <path to flash player .msi>